# remove a product from list if assigned

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I remove a product from a drop down list if it has been assigned to a customer?

The Id's seem in correct order. And I have made some changes, Maybe I'm missing something

```
        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {     
        UserProfile userprofile = db.UserProfiles.Find(id); 

        if (userprofile == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var deviceList = db.Devices.ToList();
        var userList = db.UserProfiles.ToList();

        foreach (var user in userList)
        {
            deviceList.RemoveAll(x=>x.DeviceID==user.Device_DeviceID);          

        }

            ViewBag.deviceList = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "DeviceIMEI", userprofile.Device_DeviceID);              
            return View(userprofile);

    }

    // POST: /User/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile userprofile)
    {                     
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           db.Entry(userprofile).State = EntityState.Modified;

            //db.UserProfiles.Attach(userprofile);

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.deviceList= new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceID", "DeviceIMEI", userprofile.Device_DeviceID);            
        return View(userprofile);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `RemoveAll` method.

```
 var deviceList = db.Devices.ToList();
 var userList = db.UserProfiles.ToList();
 foreach (var user in userList)
 {
    deviceList.RemoveAll(x=>x.DeviceID==user.Device_DevideID);
 }
```

Now you can bind `devicelist` to your views' dropdown. I strongly recommend to avoid using the ViewBag/ViewData approach and switch to strongly typed views approach.

Comment: Is this what you mean, it does not remove values from list.

Comment: Do you have the IDs(DeviceID and Device_DevideID's coming properly) ? Use breakpoints to see those.

Comment: I was not calling deviceList!